# Python with Selenium - selecting a button or text action

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am, poorly, trying to 1. Click a button or 2. Check for text and then execute an action. I think I am just not coding this correctly.

eg

```
if driver.find_element_by_class_name('classOne').click()
elif:
    "No Item" in driver.find_element_by_class_name('classTwo').driver.get(self_base_url)
```

This seems pretty simplistic, and I'm sure I've done something horribly wrong. This 'should' work, but isn't?

Comment: Are you trying to check for text that should appear after you've clicked on the button or checking to make sure the button you are clicking is the correct one?

Comment: I ended up checking for the presence of the text first, if it does not exist there will be a button where the text would be, and I 'click' the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `driver` can't find an element, it will raise [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException).

In your case, you can do:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classOne')
if len(x) > 0:
    # click the first one found
    x[0].click()
else:
    print('No item x was found.')
```

Notice that I changed it to `find_elements_by_class_name` from `find_element_by_class_name`. This finds all elements if there are any and returns a list.